# Setting up GeoServer Image Mosaic plug in to pick up images from directory dynamically?

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

I have set up Image Mosaic to load GeoTIFF images from a directory and it is all good but when I add more GeoTIFF files to the directory they do not show up in the mosaic unless I recreate it.

Is there a way to configure Image Mosaic to pick them up automatically?

Answer (score 3):

The image mosaic plugin holds the information about the tiles/images in an index which is either a shapefile or a database. To make the new images show up you need to update the index. This is tricky if you are using the default shapefile but easy if you are using postgis.

For postgis you just issue an SQL insert statement with the name, location and bounds of the new images (check the existing table to show you what the column order is).

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of GeoServer you can use the REST api to ingest additional granules.

ImageMosaic would not pick up new images automatically, but you could use the REST api to automate this. 
You can check [this link](http://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/multidim/en/rest/index.html) for additional information.